# Save and object from an API Call in Componente state

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, state

I'm getting started with React and i'm trying to just make a call to an api that returns an object and just print the result by saving it in the state. But for what the message says, I'm missing something in the initialisation of the state.

This is what I'm doing:

```
const apiAddress = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1';
class Caller extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
        super(props)
      this.state = { scene: ""}
  }
  ComponentWillMount () {
    fetch(apiAddress)
      .then((response) => {
        return response.json()
      })
      .then((resource) => {
        console.log(resource);
        this.setState({ scene: resource })
      });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        Res: {this.state.scene}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Caller />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

The response is this object:

```
{
  "userId": 1,
  "id": 1,
  "title": "sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit",
  "body": "quia et suscipit\nsuscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum\nreprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam\nnostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto"
}
```

And the error I'm getting is this one:

> Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys
>   {userId, id, title, body}). If you meant to render a collection of
>   children, use an array instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to render a raw object, which I don't think is valid when rendering children in React.

Try printing object values separately:

```
...
render() {
    const { userId, id, title, body } = this.state.scene
    return (
      <>
        <div> User ID: {userId}</div>
        <div> Id: {id}</div>
        <div> Title: {title}</div>
        <div> Body: {body}</div>
      </>    
   )
}
...
```

Comment: It worked.  I think I took for granted a toString() method by default. Am i to wrong? I can only put String in the { }, isn't it?

Comment: @Xhark React documentation says nothing about JSON objects, looking in the [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#children-in-jsx) of JSX you can see that nulls, numbers, booleans and functions can also be valid children, while raw objects are not. However you can easily create a component to print anything, something like [this](https://github.com/mrose/react-dump)

Comment: So there is no way to initiate an state parameters as object? Because I think that my way of initialise the state.scene variable is not adequate, but i'm not sure how i should do it.

Comment: @Xhark you can definitely initiate state parameters as an object, you just have to render those parameters properly, if you want a quick solution, use `JSON.stringify(this.state.scene)`